# Replicate MLPClassifier() of sklearn in keras

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network, classification, keras, sequential

I am new to keras. I was attempting an ML problem.
About the data:

It has 5 input features, 4 output classes and about 26000 records.

I had first attempted it using MLPClassifier() as follows:

```
clf = MLPClassifier(verbose=True, tol=1e-6, batch_size=300, hidden_layer_sizes=(200,100,100,100), max_iter=500, learning_rate_init= 0.095, solver='sgd', learning_rate='adaptive', alpha = 0.002)
clf.fit(train, y_train)
```

After testing, I usually got a LB score around 99.90. To gain more flexibility over the model, I decided to implement the same model in Keras to start with and then make changes in it in an attempt to increase the LB score. I came up with the following:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(200, input_dim=5, init='uniform', activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(100, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, init='uniform', activation='softmax'))

lrate = 0.095
decay = lrate/125
sgd = SGD(lr=lrate, momentum=0.9, decay=decay, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
hist = model.fit(train, categorical_labels, nb_epoch=125, batch_size=256, shuffle=True,  verbose=2)
```

The model seems pretty similar to the MLPClassifier() model but the LB scores were pretty disappointing at around 97.
Can somebody please tell what exactly was wrong with this model? Or how can we replicate the MLPClassifier model in keras. I think regularisation might be one of the factors that went wrong here.

Edit 1: Loss curve:
[image]

Edit 2:
Here is the code:

```
#import libraries
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, scale, StandardScaler, Normalizer

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras import regularizers
from keras.optimizers import SGD

#load data
train = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

#generic preprocessing 
#encode as integer
mapping = {'Front':0, 'Right':1, 'Left':2, 'Rear':3}
train = train.replace({'DetectedCamera':mapping})
test = test.replace({'DetectedCamera':mapping})
#renaming column
train.rename(columns = {'SignFacing (Target)': 'Target'}, inplace=True)
mapping = {'Front':0, 'Left':1, 'Rear':2, 'Right':3}
train = train.replace({'Target':mapping})


#split data
y_train = train['Target']
test_id = test['Id']
train.drop(['Target','Id'], inplace=True, axis=1)
test.drop('Id',inplace=True,axis=1)
train_train, train_test, y_train_train, y_train_test = train_test_split(train, y_train)

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(train_train)
train_train = scaler.transform(train_train)
train_test = scaler.transform(train_test)
test = scaler.transform(test)

#training and modelling
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(200, input_dim=5, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
# model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# model.add(Dense(100, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
# model.add(Dense(100, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(100, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='softmax'))

lrate = 0.095
decay = lrate/250
sgd = SGD(lr=lrate, momentum=0.9, decay=decay, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
hist = model.fit(train_train, categorical_labels, validation_data=(train_test, categorical_labels_test), nb_epoch=100, batch_size=256, shuffle=True,  verbose=2)
```

Edit 3: These are the files:
[train.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9mrNUPesd0EMGozdEpKNE5lQWs/view?usp=sharing)
[test.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9mrNUPesd0EUHM2V2VRa0JORnM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you give more details about your training history? Did you plot loss and accuracy over time and can you show the curves ?

Comment: Added the plot. The above plot was obtained when I divided the train data into train and test and the ran on the same model. The actual labels for test data for which the LB score was obtained can't be accessed. The accuracy remains at around 96 after the initial 25 epochs and the loss remains around 0.10.

Comment: Some things that come to mind: Remove the dropout layer since you don´t seem to overfit. Train longer or at least add an EarlyStopping in Keras with a patience of maybe 15 to make sure your model really isn´t improving anymore (your MLP had 500 epochs max). Try `adam` or `rmsprop` as optimizers. And just for further experiments you could add a `validation_split` in the `fit( … )` function and do a callback to Tensorboard. That gives you near realtime feedback during training.

Comment: And one more thing: It´ seems strange that train and test loss run so smoothly in parallel. Are you sure that those two data sets have correctly been separated? And have you achieved your Kaggle Leaderboard score with the sklearn Classifier on Kaggle or locally?

Comment: It doesnt seem to overfit and that's what is confusing. Because when I run the same model on the final testing data, the loss turns out to be way more than what it comes during training and validation locally. Without dropout, the loss is similar locally but on submission the LB score comes around 92! The scores mentioned are not local and rather the scores obtained on submission. Splitting of data was done using train_test_split of sklearn in .75:.25 ratio. I had sent the validation data in the fit(...) function using validation_data(). Didn't try adam. Will let you know once i try!

Comment: Also in the sklearn classifier, it did test for tolerance for every consecutive iterations and so it never ran for over 100 iterations.

Comment: One explanation would be that somehow train & test data are not separated. Your model is accidentally trained on all the data and therefore train/test losses are similar. On unseen data you then get a worse score. I know that this seems unlikely because you split with sklearn. You might add your full code above so that we can double check.

Comment: I have added the code. Also I did try adam but it did not improve...infact the convergence ended up being poorer.

Comment: Thanks. Looks good to me. And then I´m stuck too. I don´t see any good reason for this behaviour. Sorry about that. Hope sbdy else can help.

Comment: What version of sklearn are you using ?

Comment: @SerafeimLoukas the version is 0.18.1

Comment: @PriyanshuGoyal so you have the latest version . Try to print the data after the splitting (print the train_train, train_test etc) to verify that the function splits the data correctly. Also if you want add the train and test csv files to try to replicate your problem on my laptop

Comment: @SerafeimLoukas Sorry for the late reply. I have added the required files as well.

Comment: @PriyanshuGoyal okay I will try to replicate the problem asap

Comment: @PriyanshuGoyal where you define categorical_labels? I tried to run your code but categorical_labels is not defined.

Comment: Forgot to add that part. categorical_labels=to_categorical(train_train, num_classes=2) and similarly for categoriacal_labels_test, which is on train_test.

Comment: @PriyanshuGoyal Any luck so far

Answer (score 3):

To get a bona fide scikit [estimator](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.BaseEstimator.html) you can use `KerasClassifier` from [`tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn/KerasClassifier). For example:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier


X, y = make_classification(
    n_samples=26000, n_features=5, n_classes=4, n_informative=3, random_state=0
)


def build_fn(optimizer):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(
        Dense(200, input_dim=5, kernel_initializer="he_normal", activation="relu")
    )
    model.add(Dense(100, kernel_initializer="he_normal", activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(100, kernel_initializer="he_normal", activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(100, kernel_initializer="he_normal", activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(4, kernel_initializer="he_normal", activation="softmax"))
    model.compile(
        loss="categorical_crossentropy",
        optimizer=optimizer,
        metrics=[
            keras.metrics.Precision(name="precision"),
            keras.metrics.Recall(name="recall"),
            keras.metrics.AUC(name="auc"),
        ],
    )
    return model


clf = KerasClassifier(build_fn, optimizer="rmsprop", epochs=500, batch_size=300)
clf.fit(X, y)
clf.predict(X)
```