# From SKLearn to Keras - What is the difference?

Tags: keras

I'm trying to go from **SKLearn** to **Keras** in order to make specific improvements to my models.
However, I can't get the same performance I had with my **SKLearn** model :

```
mlp = MLPClassifier(
    solver='adam', activation='relu',
    beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, learning_rate='constant',
    alpha=0, hidden_layer_sizes=(238,),
    max_iter=300
)
dev_score(mlp)
```

Gives ~0.65 score everytime

Here is my corresponding **Keras** code :

```
def build_model(alpha):
    level_moreargs = {'kernel_regularizer':l2(alpha), 'kernel_initializer': 'glorot_uniform'}
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units=238, input_dim=X.shape[1], **level_moreargs))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dense(units=class_names.shape[0], **level_moreargs)) # output
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, # like sklearn
                  optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

k_dnn = KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_model, epochs=300, batch_size=200, validation_data=None, shuffle=True, alpha=0.5, verbose=0)

dev_score(k_dnn)
```

From looking at the documentation (and digging into SKLearn code), *this should correspond exactly to the same thing*.

However, I get ~0.5 accuracy when I run this model, *which is very bad*.

And if I set alpha to 0, SKLearn's score barely changes (0.63), while Keras's goes random from 0.2 to 0.4.

What is the difference between these models ? Why is Keras, although being supposed to be better than SKLearn, outperformed by so far here ? *What's my mistake* ?

Thanks,

Comment: Similar (unsolved) thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44639940/replicate-mlpclassifier-of-sklearn-in-keras?noredirect=1#comment76280905_44639940

Comment: Did you try to set random state to specific value ?

Comment: With or without random_state, SKLearn's MLP performs correctly.